# Simulating using conditional density - is this correct?

Tags: sampling, density-function, bivariate

Consider the pair of random variables $(X, Y)$ whose density is given by $$f(x, y)=yx^{y-1}e^{-y}1_{(0, \infty)}(y)1_{(0, 1)}(x)$$
I was first asked to find the density of $Y$. This was simple, that's a marginal density and I easily got $$f_{Y}(y)=e^{-y}\cdot 1_{(0, \infty)}(y),$$ so $Y\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$.
Then, I was asked to find the density of $X$ conditioned at $Y=y$ and again I easily got by mere substitutions $$f_{X|Y}(x|y)=yx^{y-1}1_{(0, 1)}(x).$$
Now, the final question of the exercise I am working on is to come up with an algorithm to sample from the density $f(x, y)$.
I haven't sampled much from bivariate densities, but since the exercise had these first tasks I thought that I should make use of the relation $$f(x, y)=f_{X|Y}(x|y)\cdot f_Y(y).$$
Sampling from $f_Y$ is easy, I can just use the inverse method. Now I am a bit confused about sampling from $f_{X|Y}$. Should I, in general, just treat the $y$ in the expression of this density as a "constant" that is simulated independently (by the inverse method in this case) and just focus on the $x$ part? If that is the case, I think that I could somehow use rejection sampling to simulate from $f_{X|Y}$, even though I am a bit unsure how and I need some help (I thought about rejection sampling because my $x$ is bounded). I am also really unsure if sampling like this would produce the correct result, I just used pure intuition.

Comment: Your intuition sounds excellent.  As far as sampling from the conditional density goes, it's easiest to use the inverse CDF.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your response! The inverse CDF is $F^{-1}(u|y)=u^{1/y}$ (is my notation correct? i just learned conditional stuff) if my calculations are correct, so I think that the algorithm I am looking for should be something like 1) Sample $Y\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$. 2) Sample $U\sim \mathcal{U}([0, 1])$. 3) Compute $X=U^{1/Y}$. 4) Return $(X, Y)$?

Comment: @JustAnAmateur:  You can answer your own Q now!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks for confirming that was right! I might add that as an answer, for the time being I am happy that I managed to do well on my statistics final exam :D.